# How to Store file_paths for fast matching queries?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to store the file path of all files in a **BUCKET**. In my case a bucket can have millions of files. I have to display that folder structure in a UI for navigation.

```
storage_folder:
  - bucket_1
    - bucket_files.txt
    - bucket_metadata.txt
  - bucket_2
    - bucket_files.txt
    - bucket_metadata.txt

# bucket_file.txt contains

folder1/sub_folder1/file1.txt
folder1/sub_folder1/file2.zip
folder1/sub_folder2/file1.txt
folder2/.....
....
....
```

#### Current approach:

I will create a `.txt` file corresponding to each **BUCKET** which will contain absolute paths of each file in that bucket. Then whenever a query comes the whole file goes through lots of string matching which is really slow.

#### What I want:

I want to store those files in a tree based structure for optimized queries.

#### Type of queries:

a. List the contents of a particular directory.
b. Prefix-search

Also, the files is not stored in memory for the next query.

Is there any solution for this? for context I am building my backend in Django.

Comment: The question is what kind of queries do you want to execute ? E.g. search by extension, by size or whatever.
Also, do you execute multiple queries in the one session? I mean to read the files list just once and to store the info in some list/dict,  at least in this way to go to the entire list will be faster starting with the 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

Completing a previous comment, once you know by which attribute you want to search, you only have to use a database table.

The efficient "tree based structure" you wish you had exists in all relational database systems in btree indexes.

Unless you do this a an exercise, don't try to create a custom structure.

Comment: I know there will be something. But can you tell what is that something? Like in case of django or sqlite.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).